# run more than one CCAction with same CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, kobold2d, ccaction

I'm currently developing a mobile game with Kobold2d (cocos2d), but I having some trouble to animate one CCSprite with more than one animation. My question is: With the same CCSprite (player) how to animate it with two different animation. I'm using Kobold2D 2.0.4 and Xcode 4.6, and for animation I have a textureAtlas compressed with pvr.ccz.

I create an animation helper class:

```
+(CCAnimation *) startFrames:(int) startFrame
                 endFrame:(int) endFrame
                frameName:(NSString *) frameName
                    delay:(float) delay
{
    NSMutableArray *frames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:endFrame];
    CCSpriteFrameCache *sharedFrameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

    for (int i = startFrame; i <= endFrame; i++) {
        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [sharedFrameCache spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.png",frameName,i]];
        [frames addObject:frame];
    }

    return [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:delay];
}

+(CCAnimation *) jumpPoints:(CGPoint[]) points
                startFrames:(int) startFrame
                   endFrame:(int) endFrame
                  frameName:(NSString *) frameName
                      delay:(float) delay
{
    NSMutableArray *frames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:endFrame];
    CCSpriteFrameCache *sharedFrameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

    for (int i = startFrame; i <= endFrame; i++) {
        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [sharedFrameCache spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i.png",frameName,i]];
        [frame setOffsetInPixels:points[i]];
        [frames addObject:frame];
    }

    return [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:delay];
}
```

I got a player class where I initialize the player and create two CCAnimation. In header file I store two CCAnimate type variables:

```
CCAnimate *jump;
CCAnimate *walk;
```

In .m file

```
-(id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {        
        sprite = [[Loading shareLoading] loadTempCcsprite];
        CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        localPostion = CGPointMake(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);

        CGPoint points[] = {CGPointMake(0, 10),CGPointMake(0, 50),CGPointMake(0, 80),
            CGPointMake(0, 10),CGPointMake(0, 0)};
        CCAnimation *animationJump = [CCAnimationHelper jumpPoints:points startFrames:0 endFrame:4 frameName:@"cactus" delay:0.10f];

        jump = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animationJump];

        CCAnimation *animationWalk = [CCAnimationHelper startFrames:0 endFrame:4 frameName:@"cactus" delay:0.10f];

        walk = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animationWalk];

        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Finally, I have input layer where the user got two jump button and attack and Joystick to move the player.

Here is the code:

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    if ([jump active])
    {
        CCAnimate *animation = [player jump];
        [player runAction:animation];
    }
    else if (joystick.velocity.x > 0)
    {
        float velocity = [joystick velocity].x * 700 * delta;

        CGPoint playerPosition = CGPointMake([player localPostion].x + velocity * delta, [player localPostion].y    );

        id animation = [player walk];
        [player runAction:animation];
        [player setLocalPostion:playerPosition];
    }
}
```

If I compile this code, in Input layer when I press jump button the game crash and the output console says:

*** Assertion failure in -[CCActionManager addAction:target:paused:]

Comment: whats the assertion error message ?

Comment: When compiler go on this instruction [player runAction:animation]; console output is this: 2013-04-03 13:08:35.258 CactusJourney-iOS[920:c07] dealloc: <LevelSelection = 0x12394340 | Tag = -1>
2013-04-03 13:08:36.454 CactusJourney-iOS[920:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[CCActionManager addAction:target:paused:], /Users/User/Kobold2D/Kobold2D-2.0.4/__Kobold2D__/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d/CCActionManager.m:171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run the same action again while it is still running.

To avoid this situation, always call stopAction before runAction:

```
[player stopAction:animation];
[player runAction:animation];
```